# echo Alert only once based on if statement PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, woocommerce

This function scrapes my shopping cart for a particular product, and if that product exists, removes shipping services. E.G. if product id:40 is in the cart, disable shipping service values in array($shipping_services_to_hide).

I would like to display a message to customers that notifies them of the shipping restriction, in the form of an alert or preferably injecting code into the cart in a specific place (based on class -no div id available-. Also,using :before or :after with css content: would be acceptable)(no idea if this part can be done)

What would be a good way to do that?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','hide_shipping_method_if_particular_product_available_in_cart' , 10, 2 );

function hide_shipping_method_if_particular_product_available_in_cart( $available_shipping_methods ) {

global $woocommerce;

// products_array should be filled with all the products ids 
// for which shipping method (stamps) to be restricted.
$products_array = array( 
40
);

// You can find the shipping service codes by doing inspect element using 
// developer tools of chrome. Code for each shipping service can be obtained by 
// checking 'value' of shipping option.
$shipping_services_to_hide  = array( 
  'wf_shipping_ups:12',
  'wf_shipping_ups:02',
  'wf_shipping_ups:59',
  'wf_shipping_ups:01',
  'wf_shipping_ups:13',
  'wf_shipping_ups:14',
  'wf_shipping_ups:11',
  'wf_shipping_ups:07',
  'wf_shipping_ups:54',
  'wf_shipping_ups:08',
  'wf_shipping_ups:65'
  );

// Get all products from the cart.
$products = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// Crawl through each items in the cart.
foreach ( $products as $key => $item ) {
    // If any product id from the array is present in the cart,
    // unset all shipping method services part of shipping_services_to_hide array. 
    if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $products_array ) ) { 
        foreach ( $shipping_services_to_hide as &$value ) {
            unset( $available_shipping_methods[ $value ] );

        }
        break;
    }
}

// return updated available_shipping_methods;
return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a notice with [`wc_add_notice()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/includes/wc-notice-functions.php#L75)

```
if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $products_array ) ) { 
    foreach ( $shipping_services_to_hide as &$value ) {
        unset( $available_shipping_methods[ $value ] );
        // add your notice here
        wc_add_notice( 'No shipping error.', 'your-plugin' ), 'notice' );
    }
    break;
}
```